# How do I automate a video download with Selenium and Python (Meta Quest Store Trailer Download)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, video, automation

I am looking to automate the download of the .mp4 video from https://www.meta.com/en-gb/experiences/4979055762136823/ using python and the selenium package. I am able to pop up and play the video with

```
url = "https://www.meta.com/en-gb/experiences/4979055762136823/"
driver.get(url)
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'#mdc-main-content > div > div > div > div > main > div > div > div > div._anfv._anfz._anfy').click()
time.sleep(2)
video = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'#mdc-main-content > div > div > div > div > main > div > div > div > div._anfv._anfw._anfy > div._ane1 > div._ane2 > div._aneb > div:nth-child(2) > div > video > source').get_attribute('src')
```

I am also able to grab the src url but am unable to download using requests (getting HTTP Error 403: Forbidden), but I want to be able to click on the download button each time and then save the mp4 file via the browser, is this possible with selenium ?. [image]

Alternatively if I am able to download the src somehow. The src is https://scontent.oculuscdn.com/v/t64.7195-25/10000000_1333543020822103_5659386953994694484_n.mp4.

Thanks in advance.